# How to copy a .c file to a numbered listing

Tags: bash, unix

I simply want to copy  my .c file into a  line-numbered listing file. Basically generate a .prn file from my .c file. I'm having a hard time finding the right bash command to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my linux system, I occasionally use `pr -tn` to prefix line numbers for listings.  The -t option suppresses headers and footers; -n says to prefix line numbers.  -n allows optional format and digit specifiers; see man page.  Anyhow, to print file xyz.c to xyz.prn with line numbering, use:

```
pr -tn xyz.c > xyz.prn
```

Note, this is not as compact and handy as `cat -n xyz.c > xyz.prn` (using `cat -n` as suggested in a previous answer); but `pr` has numerous other options, and I most often use it when I want to both number the lines and put them into multiple columns or print multiple files side by side.  Eg for a 2-column numbered listing use:

```
pr -2 -tn xyz.c > xyz.prn
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean `nl`?

```
nl -ba filename.c
```

The `-ba` means to number all lines, not just non-empty ones.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print FNR ":" $0}' file1 file2 ...
```

is one way.

FNR is FileNumberRecord (the current line number per file).

You can change the ":" per your needs.

`$0` means "the-whole-line-of-input"

Or you can do

```
 cat -n file1 file2 ....
```

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

I think shellter has the right idea. However, if your require output written to files with `prn` extensions, here's one way:

```
awk '{ sub(/\.c$/, "", FILENAME); print FNR ":" $0 > FILENAME ".prn" }' file1.c file2.c ...
```

To perform this on all files in the present working directory:

```
for i in *.c; do awk '{ sub(/\.c$/, "", FILENAME); print FNR ":" $0 > FILENAME ".prn" }' "$i"; done
```